# Wordpress 3.2 Admin UI Guide

Tags: wp-admin, user-interface

Is there such a guide somewhere so that I could use standard UI elements (especially since the 3.2 rewrite) instead of marking up my own?

Like the Categories metabox tabs for example.

Answer (score 3):

Do you will use default elements of WP for your custom development, right? Than is this plugin maybe an helper: https://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Admin-Style

Comment: Cool plugin! :) But is there any documentation somewhere on the metabox tabs I mentioned?

Comment: if you will include taps on the meta box, use the jQuery UI, she is include the core and works fine with WP. Current give it only tabs on the theme page, but he is to big and not formated for the meta box. I inlcude always the jquery UI Tabs.

Comment: right, WP has not an default for tabs in meta boxes, you must include an custom solution with jQuery UI.